# Printing all global variables in one source file with gdb?

Tags: gdb

I am including few libraries to my program, so `info variables` takes more than 2 minutes to print all global variables.

Is it possible to print the global variables in **just one source file**? Or is it possible to speed up `info variables`?

Comment: One workaround perhaps is to load the object file e.g. gdb foo.o then run info var, which at least seems to work when the object file was compiled with debug info.

Comment: Works flawlessly. Thank you. I have been loading the elf file.